# setMyLocationEnabled for sdk 24

Tags: android

Call requires permission which may be rejected by user: code should explicitly check to see if permission is available (with checkPermission) or explicitly handle a potential `SecurityException

```
    GoogleMap mMap;
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

why?

Answer (score 0):

`setMyLocationEnabled()` requires a location permission (e.g., `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`). Those permissions have a protection level of `dangerous` and are subject to [the runtime permission rules](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html). The Lint tool thinks that you need to use runtime permissions (e.g., your `targetSdkVersion` is 23 or higher) and that you are not doing so.